# How to load multiple sections in table for Apple watch

Tags: ios, tableview, apple-watch

I'm working on demo in Apple watch. In my demo app I'm displaying two sections in tableview.

```
NSMutableArray *rowTypes= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Identifier1",@"Identifier2", nil];
[tableView setRowTypes:rowTypes];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < rowTypes.count; i++)
{
    NSString* rowType = rowTypes[i];
    ProfileObject *row =[tableView rowControllerAtIndex:i];
    if ([rowType isEqualToString:@"Identifier1"])
    {
      // load data
    }
    else
    {
      for (int j=0 ; j<array.count ;j++)
        {
         // load data
        }
    }
}
```

In Identifier1 i'm displaying single row and Identifier2 i'm displaying multiple of rows but it is only displaying single row. How can i display multiple rows in Identifier2.

Please can any one help me.

Comment: Add the same identifier multiple times: `Identifier2`.

Comment: Thanks. it's work for me.